# Adding multiple gem dependencies in gemspec

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

How do you guys add multiple development/runtime dependencies to your gemspec?

This is the way I do it:

```
spec.add_development_dependency 'example1', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.4'
spec.add_development_dependency 'example2', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.4'
```

But I'd like to know if there are other ways to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at the Gem specification from [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Gem/Specification.html#method-i-add_runtime_dependency) that seems to be the only way

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the Gem specification from [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Gem/Specification.html#method-i-add_runtime_dependency)  the choices are:

`add_dependency`, `add_runtime_dependency`, `add_development_dependency`, `add_dependency_with_type`